# SSH tunnel/bridge to a remote database

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I can't seem to wrap my head around the concept of ssh tunneling. The situation I'm currently in is that I have:

- Server **A**, which can be accessed through ssh, and inside it there's a mysql db accessed through `localhost:3306`.
- Server **B**, which has ssh access to **A**.
- MySQL instance **C** which has access to **B**. I can only access the db server, not the server itself, so I am unable to ssh anywhere from **C**. I can only connect to any port on **B**.

My goal is MySQL replication from **A** to **C**, where A is the master, and **C** - the slave. How should I proceed if I wanted to connect from **C** to **A**. I imagine it something like this diagram:

```
C ─────────B:B_PORT────────> B
                            │││
         |/─────tnl A:22────┘││
A_db <────localhost:3306─────┘│
         |\─────tnl A:22──────┘
```

So far I tried to run this on **B** `sudo ssh -L B_PORT:localhost:3306 A_user@A_ip -f -N` but I still can't seem to access **A** from **C**, when connecting to **B_PORT**.

EDIT: Also tried `ssh -L B_PORT:localhost:3306 A_user@A_ip -f -N -g` as suggested by @larsks with no avail. His explanation leads me to believe there might be issues within the network

## My journey so far

1. Create tunnel on **B** with `ssh -L B_PORT:localhost:3306 A_user@A_ip -f -N -g`
2. Connect **C** to **B**.
3. netstat on **B** shows multiple SYN_RECV connections from **C** to **B**
4. If I try to connect to **B_PORT** from **B** I get this

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to A port 22: Broken pipe
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

5. ssh connection is dropped on **B** and tunnel needs to be reopened
6. Fiddled around with security groups and other network rules. Enabled network inbound and outbound from and to **C** and everything is working!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions (both on the diagnosing and on question composing). It seems that I solved my problems and everything is alright

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `-g` option to your ssh command line:

```
     -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
             If used on a multiplexed connection, then this option
             must be specified on the master process.
```

This will expose forwarded ports on host `B` so that they are
accessible from `C`. This assumes your firewall configuration on `B`
permits these connections.

The `-g` option changes the local bind address that `ssh` uses for the local port.  Without `-g`, `-L 8000:localhost:8000` results in:

```
$ netstat -tln | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8000                :::*                    LISTEN
```

As you can see, in this case, both sockets are bound to the loopback address (`127.0.0.1` for ipv4 and `::1` for ipv6).

With `-g`, we instead get:

```
$ netstat -tln | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

In this case, you can see that `ssh` is now binding to the wildcard address instead of the loopback address.

Comment: Executed `sudo ssh -L B_PORT:localhost:3306 A_user@A_ip -f -N -g` on B. Still cannot connect from C. Will try to investigate firewall issues and etc. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. After running your command I can see the incoming connections in netstat. They're stuck on SYN_RECV, so I will investigate further. Thank you

Comment: I don't like this answer, it does not seem to address your problem. Why did you accept it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor what about this answer doesn't seem to address the problem? Using `-g` to open up ports to external connections seems to be exactly what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Now that the question is amended. I see that this may be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why the `sudo`? `sudo` is not the answer to all problems, and often the cause.

I think this is what you want.

```
ssh -L local_port:remote_ip:remote_port jump_user@jump_ip
ssh -L C_PORT:A_ip:3306 B_user@B_ip -f -N
```

- remote is from jump's perspective
- jump is from local's perspective

Comment: These commands should be executed from B? Why interchangeably use "local, jump, remote" notation and my "A B C" notation when it might cause more confusion. Or are they interchangeable?

Comment: You run it from C (the place that you said you want to connect from). I have given two examples. The first is more generic, the 2nd is for your case.

Comment: As I said, I cannot run commands from C, I only have access to the db directly.

Thank you for clarifying the examples.

Comment: I think you will need to edit you question, to make it clear what you are trying to do.